# How to pass values to other component in React-Native-Router-Flux?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

My code is:

```
...
<Router>
 <Scene key="com1" component={Com1} initial/>
<Scene key="com2" component={Com2}/>
</Router>
...
com1.js
...
onPress={Actions.com2}
```

I changed `com1` to `com2`.

But I need to pass values for the inputbox of `Com1` to `Com2`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can pass data like this:

> Actions.com2 ({text: 'Hello World'})

You can recover your data in com2 like this:

> this.props.text

You can go to the next tutorial for more information:

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/v3/MINI_TUTORIAL.md

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @achu are you using Redux too?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to that, (and for those in the comments who said it didn't work) you may want to try below. When you pass the

```
Actions.com2({text : 'Hello World'});
```

Com2 should pass 'props'

```
const Com2 = (props) => {
   return ( <View ...
    {props.text}
   ... />
);
```

Comment: What if I'm using a class-based component?

Answer (score 4):

Pass data through an Input,

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import { Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
   import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

   export default class Com1 extends Component {
   state = { text: '' };
      render() {
       return (
          <View>
             <TextInput
                value={this.state.text}
                onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
            />
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressNext.bind(this)}>
   <Text>Get Data</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    );
}

onPressNext() {
    Actions.Com2({text: this.state.text });
}
}
```

To get value in the second Page

```
   export default class Com2 extends Component {

      render() {
         return (
        <View>
         <Text>
          {this.props.text}
         </Text>
       </View>
    );
  }
 }
```

You can refer to this link:
https://react-native-solutions.blogspot.com/2018/07/passing-data-between-screens-in-react.html

Answer (score 1):

Use push method as below:

```
Actions.push('your key name',{prop you want to pass})
```

It pushes the scene to the stack, performing a transition to the new scene.

Comment: Please format your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code for better readability. A link to the docu would also improve the quality of your answer.