# React Native Touchable Opacity OnPress using data

Tags: react-native

My objective here is that I have 2 screens and I want to show the output whenever I click using `TouchableOpacity`. For example, the first screen will show a `Flatlist` of the title from my data First,Second and Third. So what I want it to do is if I press First, it will move me to another screen and show the output `FlatList` a,b,c. If I press Second, it will move me to another screen and show 1,2,3. So I am not sure how to move to another screen using `TouchableOpacity`

This is my data

```
const Clusdata = 
[
{ title: 'First', 
  example: 
 [
 {name: 'a'},
 {name: 'b'},
 {name: 'c'},
 ],
},
{ title: 'Second', 
  example: 
 [
 {name: '1'},
 {name: '2'},
 {name: '3'},
 ],
},
{ title: 'Third', 
  example: 
 [
 {name: '4'},
 {name: '5'},
 {name: '6'},   
 ],
}
]
```

This is my `Flatlist` for the first screen that I can show

```
export default class Cluster1 extends Component{
render() {

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={ClusData}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return <FlatListItem item={item} index={index} />;
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
}

class FlatListItem extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
          <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{this.props.item.title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
}
```

I created another class but I don't know what to store inside so I left it blank

```
class FlatlistExample extends Component {

}
```

Comment: What do you want to ask? About `Flatlist` or `TouchableOpacity `?

Comment: TouchableOpacity. When I press First, I want it to go to another screen and show  the data a,b,c in a flatlist. The part where I am not sure is the onPress function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Going to another screen* means navigating in react-native. React native doesn't have any out of the box navigation solutions but there are lots of navigation libraries that you can use. To be able to achieve what you want to do you need to find a suitable navigation library for your project and implement it in your project. Most of the libraries support some sort of parameter sending in navigate actions/functions. After you implemented your navigation library you can use that ability to achieve desired structure.

You can find lots of navigation related libraries in [`awesome-react-native` repo](https://github.com/jondot/awesome-react-native#navigation).

Comment: I am using react-native-router-flex. How do I send data to another screen?

Comment: You should do more research. [How to pass values to other component in React-Native-Router-Flux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39611634/2315280)

Answer (score -1):

Use this: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux.

Send data to another view: `Actions.view_name({key: value,key1:value1,key2:value2})`

Comment: Hi can you explain to me the key part?

Comment: Please read document, i think it's easy to understand, you can download example and apply your project