# Passing props in nested sceen react native router flux

Tags: android, react-native

I need some help is passing props from one sceen to other in react native using router flux.
If sceen are not nested im able to pass props as Actions.sceen_Key(Param).
My route.js

```
<Scene key="root">    
<Scene key="drawer" drawer={true} contentComponent={menu} drawerIcon= 
{menuicon} drawerWidth={300} hideNavBar>
<Scene key="Login" component={Login} title="My App" ></Scene>
<Scene key="Sceen1" component={Sceen1} title="Sceen1"></Scene>
<Scene key="Sceen2" component={Sceen2} title="Sceen2"></Scene>
</Scene>
</Scene>
```

In Sceen1.js im calling Actions.Sceen2({ID:"tesing"})
Navigation is happening but if i try to access param like this.props.ID 
in not not getting any value, also when i tried to use alert(props) in sceen2.js actions are empty.

Comment: please refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611634/how-to-pass-values-to-other-component-in-react-native-router-flux

Comment: Thanks but the solution proposed is not for nested screens.